# View.OnDragListener() method does not invoke

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this custom `AppCompatImageView` class. When the layout is inflated I see the constructor is called and the listener is set from the logs

> DragView2()
>
> listener set

But I don't see logs indicating the listner method `View.OnDragListener` is invoked when interacting with the custom view.

Why is `View.OnDragListener` not invoked?

Here is custom `AppCompatImageView` class

```
public class DragView2 extends AppCompatImageView
implements View.OnDragListener{

    private static final String TAG = DragView2.class.getSimpleName();

    public DragView2(Context context) {
        super(context, null);
        Log.d(TAG,"DragView2()");
        this.setOnDragListener(this);
        Log.d(TAG,"listener set");

    }

    public DragView2(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs, 0);
        Log.d(TAG,"DragView2()");
        this.setOnDragListener(this);
        Log.d(TAG,"listener set");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onDrag()");
        Log.d(TAG,"event.getAction() = "+event.getAction());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I think i have to init the drag within an onTouch listener

Comment: There are two constructor options, you do not override, implement them and try again...

Comment: @the_dani `AppCompatImageView` has `3` constructors and I override `2`, so not sure what you mean by `2 options` as I think there is only `1 option` if that is what you mean, but I did get the drag working

Answer (score 0):

I need to trigger the drag even from the `onTouch` so I acutally need to set two listeners

```
this.setOnTouchListener(this);
this.setOnDragListener(this);
```

Here is class

```
public class DragView2 extends AppCompatImageView
implements View.OnDragListener, View.OnTouchListener{

    private static final String TAG = DragView2.class.getSimpleName();

    public DragView2(Context context) {
        super(context, null);
        Log.d(TAG,"DragView2()");
        this.setOnTouchListener(this);
        this.setOnDragListener(this);
        Log.d(TAG,"listener set");

    }

    public DragView2(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs, 0);
        Log.d(TAG,"DragView2()");
        this.setOnTouchListener(this);
        this.setOnDragListener(this);
        Log.d(TAG,"listener set");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onTouch()");
        Log.d(TAG," motionEvent.getAction() = "+motionEvent.getAction());

        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(
                    view);
            view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onDrag()")
        return true;
    }
}
```